# Create a aspx file that contains multiple languages text

Tags: html, css, asp.net

**Problem:** Let say I have the following paragraph in English "Hello world!". I would like to be able to have text, in Mandarin that says the same thing, with pmingliu font.

However, when I enter both the different version of the text in multiple languages, the Mandarin generates gibberish.

Is there a way to have a aspx file that contains multiple languages text and display the text correctly if given the chance to print it out?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-language support is most easily implemented using a [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx), which can retrieve language-specific text (or other resources such as icons) from resources that are embedded in your application or contained in satellite assemblies.

Sample code:

```
// C#
// Gets a reference to the same assembly that 
// contains the type that is creating the ResourceManager.
var myAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
var myManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", myAssembly);

// Gets a reference to a different assembly.
var myOtherAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("ResourceAssembly");

// Retrieves String and Image resources.
var myString = myManager.GetString("StringResource");
var myImage = (System.Drawing.Image)myManager.GetObject("ImageResource");
```

Resources can be language-specific:

> In the satellite assembly deployment model, you create an application with a default assembly (the main assembly) and several satellite assemblies. You package the resources for the default or neutral culture with the main assembly, and create a separate satellite assembly for each language that your application supports. Because the satellite assemblies are not part of the main assembly, you can easily replace or update resources that correspond to a specific culture without replacing the main assembly for the application.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Is there no other approach to achieve what I am asking?

Comment: Of course there is.  There are thousands of ways to show text on a page.  But this is the way that was specifically designed for internationalization.  Do you have additional system constraints that you haven't made explicit?

Comment: I am just curious on other approaches. I have been researching but I am not able to find other approaches besides the one you have presented

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatives to using resource files

Resources are the #1 way to go and are extremely common, since they were designed for this purpose.  However there are some alternatives since you seem to be interested.

1. Use a [content management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) or CMS.  While this is a huge effort to create and maintain, it provides the most flexibility, including the ability to review changes before pushing them into production mode.
2. Deploy separate web pages for each language or culture.  This multiplies the number of pages you need to maintain, so it is not common.  It has the advantage that the layout can be culturally specific, which might be important if the language of interest is read from right to left or top to bottom, or if translated text is much shorter or longer than the default language.  There may be [other cultural considerations as well](http://www.creativebloq.com/design/cultural-factors-web-design-3135752).
3. Roll your own.  I worked on a project once where all text resources were stored in a database.  You could also store them all in flat files or obtain them from a service.  The possibilities are limited only by your imagination.